# search with multi textbox windows form c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

```
public void filter()  
{  
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))  
    {  
         SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * From Customer", sqlconn);  
         DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();  
         sqlad.Fill(dtbl);  
         DataView dv = dtbl.DefaultView;  
         dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%' and Address like '%{0}% and  office_number like '" + searchoffice.Text + "%'and phone_number like '" + searchphone.Text + "%' and acount_name like '%{0}%'", searchname.Text,searchaddress.Text,searchoffice.Text,searchphone.Text,searchaccountname.Text);  
            customergrid.DataSource = dv.ToTable();  
            dtbl.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] DESC";  
    }  
}
```

When I run this method in the `textbox.textchange()`-EventHandler, I get following Exception:

```
The expression contains an invalid string constant: '
```

Please help me fix the exception.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your query string was missing one space near `office_number like '" + searchoffice.Text + "%' and phone_number`, also there was one '-character missing and String.Format- parameter count mismatch.

So try following:

```
public void filter()  
    {  
        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIBSL6N;Initial Catalog=sales_management;Integrated Security=True"))  
        { 
            SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * From Customer", sqlconn);  
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();  
            sqlad.Fill(dtbl);  
            DataView dv = dtbl.DefaultView;  
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%' and Address like ‘%{1}%’ and  office_number like '" + searchoffice.Text + "%' and phone_number like '" + searchphone.Text + "%' and acount_name like '%{0}%'", searchname.Text,searchaddress.Text);  
            customergrid.DataSource = dv.ToTable();  
            dtbl.DefaultView.Sort = "[Name] DESC";  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: It seems, that there was some '-character also missing, check updated version?

Comment: Also there was mismatch of String.Format parameter count and indices. It will be cleaner to have only format parameter {0},{1} etc and not mixed with inline-string concatenation..

Comment: another error occured: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String.

Comment: Now you have to check field datatypes and make required conversions before executing filtering. When TextBox.Text-values are strings then you have use decimal.Parse etc before search..